# Node-Red Program to display results on Labview

Tags: labview, node-red

I am running Node-Red on a Raspberry Pi 3. The node-red program allows me to run the Input/Output modules.

I was wondering if I can use LabVIEW to show my results from node red on the front panel of LabVIEW or do I have to create a separate program in LabVIEW to run my I/O modules.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the following:

1. Run your Node-Red program and communicate with the Node-Red program via LabVIEW using the Node-Red API.  You would need to rebuild the GUI in LabVIEW
2. Insert the Node-Red Webpage into LabVIEW

> If you're using windows, place an ActiveX container from the
>   containers palette on the FP, right click and select Insert ActiveX
>   object. Find the Internet Explorer object (it may be called Microsoft
>   Web Browser) and use property and invoke nodes to load the URL you
>   want.

To me either option doesn't really make sense.  If you already have LabVIEW, you could just use LabVIEW to talk with your sensors.